# Trouble Testing SwiftUI @State property Change in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-property-wrapper

#### Problem Description

I am facing an issue while trying to test a SwiftUI view with a toggle action using XCTest. The test is failing, particularly in the last `XCTAssertTrue` statement, and it seems to be related to the asynchronous nature of SwiftUI updates.

Is there any way to make the test work?

#### Code Snippets

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```swift
// XCTest Code
final class ToggleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testToggleAction() {
        // Given
        let view = ToggleView()
        XCTAssertFalse(view.toggle)
        // When
        view.handleToggleAction()
        // Then
        XCTAssertTrue(view.toggle)
    }
}

// SwiftUI View
struct ToggleView {
    @State private(set) var toggle: Bool = false

    func handleToggleAction() {
        self.toggle = true
    }
}

extension ToggleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle") {
            self.handleToggleAction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access `State` from outside a `View` also putting the `body` in an `extension` is very unorthodox it will likely affect SwiftUI's storage. In short no, this won't work.

Comment: How about writing a UITest instead?

Comment: You dont need to test View or State, Apple has already done that for us.

Comment: @malhal I'm not testing the View or State, I'm testing the `handleToggleAction ` logic which is being sure I'm changing the toggle value.

@Sweeper UITests will work but I would like to write unit tests for future code changes with complex logic or robust functionalities, I know there is a possibility of using a `ViewModel` but I won't like going that way.

Comment: Then change handleToggleAction to take a param and return a value so you can test it without the need for state to be working.